# Batch - Multiple commands if button press

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm coding a simple game and needed help,

```
pcash = user cash
reshp1 = cost to restore hp
php = player health
```

How do I write these into 1 line?

If user press 1, check if cash is equal or greater to the cost of restore hp, if it is greater - subtract cash base on cost of restore hp, then finally add the hp by 20%.

This is what I have tried, but did not work as expected.

```
if "%restorer%"=="1" if %pcash% geq %reshp1c% && set /a pcash=%pcash% - %reshp1c% && set /a php=%php% * .20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if "%restorer%"=="1" if %pcash% geq %reshp1c% set /a pcash=%pcash% - %reshp1c%&set /a php=%php%*6/5
```

`&` is used to separate cascaded statement. Batch uses integer mathematics, so `*6/5` will multiply by 6 then divide by 5, adding 20% to the prior value (your code, had it worked, would have **set** the value to 20% of its prior magnitude)

Comment: How many & can I use? And what if I have more than 3-5 if statements that I needed to add to the same line?

Comment: As many as you need. Why do you need to add them all on one line?

Comment: So I don't mix with other functions. I may also have other questions, but it's un-related to this topic. Am hoping you can help as well.